# Merge multiple CSVs on DateTime column with multiple header lines

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, merge

I've been scratching my head at this one for a while, hopefully someone can help!

I have 3 (can vary up to 5) CSVs. I have them all in a list called all_files. The CSV format is tricky. Each CSV only has the Date/Time (also has seconds) column in common. They also have the first 3 lines as a header.

*For example:*

[data structure picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV5HC.png)

All of the CSVs look like this. How to do I concat them so that all 3 header rows are at the top and the date/time is the indexed column? I will eventually need to sort by datetime and import the CSV into a software

I also have a case where there are 2 columns that overlap in 2 of the files. Is it possible to merge them? Or just always remove them off a certain file?

Comment: Can you explain the last question again? Does it means that you want remove duplicated rows?

Comment: Eventually, but for now I would like to get the files to just merge properly

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample csv files, as follows:

```
# 1.csv
Date/Time,Measurement1,Measurement2
d,units1,units2
name,mnemonic1,mnemonic2
1/4/2022 17:13,0,0.22
1/4/2022 17:27,1,1.22
1/4/2022 17:27,1.53,0.58
1/4/2022 17.27,1.69,6.55

# 2.csv
Date/Time,Measurement1,Measurement2
d,units1,units2
name,mnemonic1,mnemonic2
1/5/2022 18:13,0,1.22
1/5/2022 18:27,1,2.22
1/5/2022 18:27,1.33,0.58
1/5/2022 18.27,1.49,6.55

# 3.csv
Date/Time,Measurement1,Measurement2
d,units1,units2
name,mnemonic1,mnemonic2
1/6/2022 19:13,1,0.22
1/6/2022 19:27,2,1.22
1/6/2022 19:27,2.53,0.58
1/6/2022 19.27,2.69,6.55
```

Then, I concat all the csv files:

```
import pandas as pd

all_files = ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']
total_df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=[0, 1, 2])
    total_df = pd.concat([total_df, df])
total_df = total_df.reset_index(drop=True) # rest index numbers
print(total_df)

print(total_df.loc[1, ('Date/Time', 'd', 'name')]) # access an element you want by MultiIndex

#         Date/Time Measurement1 Measurement2
#                 d       units1       units2
#              name    mnemonic1    mnemonic2
#0   1/4/2022 17:13         0.00         0.22
#1   1/4/2022 17:27         1.00         1.22
#2   1/4/2022 17:27         1.53         0.58
#3   1/4/2022 17.27         1.69         6.55
#4   1/5/2022 18:13         0.00         1.22
#5   1/5/2022 18:27         1.00         2.22
#6   1/5/2022 18:27         1.33         0.58
#7   1/5/2022 18.27         1.49         6.55
#8   1/6/2022 19:13         1.00         0.22
#9   1/6/2022 19:27         2.00         1.22
#10  1/6/2022 19:27         2.53         0.58
#11  1/6/2022 19.27         2.69         6.55
```

As I used MultiIndex for a header (first three lines), you can access each element using MultiIndex, as follows:

```
print(total_df.loc[1, ('Date/Time', 'd', 'name')]) # access an element you want by MultiIndex
# 1/4/2022 17:27
```

Comment: Looks like it worked! I think maybe my original CSVs were corrupt or something. I just need to get Date/Time into the 1st column and sorted. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like when I sort, it is removing duplicate Date/Time values. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @superEXTmario Sorting cannot removes any rows. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Since multiple csvs had the same date/time stamps after concat, when I sorted by Date/time, it removed duplicate date/time stamps. I had to use merge instead of concat

Comment: @superEXTmario It doesn't make sense. It would be helpful if you update your code that revmoes duplicated date/time stamps on the question.